# Bricked phone due to cut-pasting of apk files

Tags: adb, boot-loop, rom, unbricking, bootloader-lock

I accidentally *cut* all the .apk and .odex files from `/system/apps/` and pasted onto the SD card instead of *copying* and pasting them. My phone is totally bricked. Stuck in a boot-loop and factory reset doesn't work (as I had assumed it wouldn't). I cannot connect ADB to it because Android OS never actually loads (hence the boot-loop). I know there's a way to fix this I just dont know how to do it yet. PLEASE HELP ME DO THIS! This is a learning experience for me (good ***and*** bad).

The phone in question is a Kyocera Hydro C5171 from Cricket. It has Android 4.0.4 ICS. It *is* rooted (that's how I was able to accomplish this horrible act of murder to my precious phone). I need to figure this out please and will do all the homework on the subject myself **if only I could get pointed in the right direction!** I just don't know where to begin. I believe that I have only one option (this is just an assumption, please don't judge me):

I have to flash the stock ROM onto the phone. If, indeed, that is the case I require a copy of the stock ROM first (I may not be searching for it right, but I can't seem to find it *anywhere* on the web. Any help on where I can find this is GREATLY appreciated!!).

Second, From what I've been reading Kyocera has locked the bootloader on this particular device and flashing the ROM is extremely difficult for seasoned veterans of this game (If this is true I will definitely need an instructor to properly guide me through the process).

Third, I have no effing idea how to even begin flashing ROMs, so, here also, I will require some form of instruction or at least be pointed to a URL that contains a decent guide to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

---

**Updates** (from the comments):

- I've got neither custom recovery nor a Nandroid backup
- I can boot into stock recovery (wipe cache, wipe data, or reboot, see [this screenshot](https://scontent-a-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10373853_635629063187695_6671453425322284135_n.jpg)), but my device is not discovered in this mode by ADB (latest drivers installed on my PC)

Comment: I've not tried that, and different stock recoveries deal differently with that, but it's worth a try: Boot into recovery, then `adb shell` to the device, make yourself root (`su`), and see if you can access both places (SDCard and `/system`). If so, try mounting `/system` read-write, and then `cp` the packages back to `/system/apps` (e.g. `cp /sdcard/folder/*.apk /system/apps` if you moved them to `/sdcard/folder` before).

Comment: With the Kyocera Hydro C5171, unfortunately, that does **not** work. I manually installed the drivers for the phone also - you know, just in case you were going to ask me if I did that next. I believe I still have root, however I have no way to enable USB debugging. This is actually a pic of the particular Recovery installed...  
<img src="https://scontent-a-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10373853_635629063187695_6671453425322284135_n.jpg">

Comment: Rather than launching into stock recovery, launch into download mode and reinstall your entire stock ROM. Find some tutorials on how to use Odin3 (flashing software) online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to a Cricket retailer (not an official store) for an unrelated issue with my new phone and, interestingly enough, they can, and will, flash the stock ROM back onto my phone. So, problem solved and lesson learned!